# How to verify the hover text (tooltip) in Cypress?

Tags: angular-material, hover, cypress, tooltip

```html
<span class="mat-button-wrapper">
  <mat-icon role="img" fragment="list" 
    class="mat-icon notranslate logo-icon s-24 mr-8 material-icons mat-icon-no-color" 
    aria-hidden="true">arrow_back</mat-icon>
</span>
```

I have tried the following tests but they do not work.

For **chrome**, it is saying there is a timeout.

For **edge**, it is not focusing on the back button instead focusing on the textbox.

Chrome:

```js
cy.get('#asset-categories>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)>button')
  .trigger('mouseover').invoke('show')
cy.contains('Back to asset categories')
```

Edge:

```
cy.get('#asset-categories>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)>button')
  .focused().realHover()
cy.contains('Back to asset categories')
```

---

If I hover the back button, "Back to asset categories" will be displayed.

[image]

Comment: But why? Do you think there's a high risk associated with the tooltip text? Why check this at all? It's a static text, that doesn't break often. Plus it's a tooltip, perhaps the last thing people look at. Isn't there something more risky that you can check with Cypress?

Comment: We find it necessary to automate the entire application. Tooltips are often important. And once you automate it, you never have to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

I have used a mouseover event to check the toolTip. 1st line in below code will hover the mouse pointer to the button and 2nd line will check if the toolTip has the text visible.

cy.get('#toolTipButton').trigger('mouseover');

cy.contains('You hovered over the Button').should('be.visible');

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have to show tooltip while hovering over a button. It is working for me. I am verifying colors, you can edit it according to your requirements. My code is as follow:

```
describe('color', () => {
  it('should have correct background color', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="button"]').realHover();
    cy.get('.mat-tooltip')
     .should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(111, 111, 111)');

  });

  it('should have correct text color', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="button"]').realHover();
    cy.get('.mat-tooltip')
    .should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `realHover`?

Comment: @Andremoniy https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events